# how to print certain column with numbers only in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file that contains a mix of different number of columns per line.

I want to only print the lines if columns 3, 4 and 5 of that line only contains number.

The trick is occasionally columns 3, 4 and 5 will have a special character "(", or ")" embedded in them, and I want to print these numbers too.

```
cat $filename | awk '{ if ( ($3 != "^[0-9]") && ($4 != "^[0-9]") && ($5 != "^[0-9]") ) print $2, $3, $4, $5 }' >>text.dat
```

But it also prints such thing as: Au2, Cu2, etc.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

A relevant part of input text file looks like this:

```
Cu1 Cu 0.00000 0.094635(14) 0.094635(14)
Cu2 Cu 0.00000 0.125943(15) 0.125943(15)
.
.
.
```

What I want is the following:

```
Cu 0.00000 0.094635 0.094635
Cu 0.00000 0.125943 0.125943
.
.
.
```

Note that "Cu" is from the string in second column from the original input file, and I've gotten rid of the number and parentheses in columns 4 and 5. Note also that the parentheses could exist in column 3 as well. Numbers in the parentheses could be single digit.

Answer (score 1):

in your codes:

```
 ($3 != "^[0-9]") && ($4 != "^[0-9]") && ($5 != "^[0-9]")
```

`!=` means `not equal to` it doesn't do regex match testing.

try `$3~/[0-9]+/ && $4~/[0-9]+/` and so on

for the `(` or `)` problem
what you could do is, before you check regex match on $2 $3 $4, replace all `( or )` in those fields with `""` then do the match testing.

I hope the explanation above is clear enough.

**EDIT**

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=5;i++)gsub(/\([^\)]*\)/,"",$i)}$3~/[0-9\.]*/&&$4~/[0-9\.]*/&&$5~/[0-9\.]*/' file
```

this line above does:

- remove (...) from $3,$4, $5
- check if $3, $4, $5 are number (or decimal).
- if yes, print line out

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "Cu1 Cu 0.00000 0.094635(14) 0.094635(14)
Cu2 Cu 0.00000 0.125943(15) 0.125943(15)"|awk '{for(i=3;i<=5;i++)gsub(/\([^\)]*\)/,"",$i)}$3~/[0-9\.]*/&&$4~/[0-9\.]*/&&$5~/[0-9\.]*/'                                               
Cu1 Cu 0.00000 0.094635 0.094635
Cu2 Cu 0.00000 0.125943 0.125943
```

only $2, $3, $4, $5:

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=5;i++)gsub(/\([^\)]*\)/,"",$i);if($3~/[0-9\.]*/&&$4~/[0-9\.]*/&&$5~/[0-9\.]*/)print $2,$3,$4,$5}' file
```

Comment: still prints lines which has a column with a combination of alphabet and number...

Comment: @Greg if you gave some input/output example, it will help you to get an answer sooner.

Comment: Thanks. but I do not want the first column printed. how do I do that?