# Saving a certain string from command line

Tags: linux, shell, debian

i am writing a bash script, and when i execute a certain command from my script it spits out an ID like this

VM ID: 12345

IDs are different all the time. How would I be able to extract just the number of ID and store it in my script?
I tried to put a ">file" after the command and it does not seem to work.

Comment: If the `>file` doesn't save string in the file, then the message isn't written to standard output.  Could it be written to standard error instead?  Or is it written to `/dev/tty`?  You may need to know which file descriptor it is written on.  You might need to use `strace` to track where it is written.

Answer (score 0):

So, it depends on the possible IDs.

If it is always the 3rd item in string.

```
echo "VM ID: 12345" | awk '{print $3}' > file
```

If the output is always the only numbers in the output you can use tr.

```
echo "VM ID: 12345" | tr -d '[:alpha:][:blank:][:punct:]'
12345
```

However, if another number is in the string it will be added.

```
echo "VM3 ID: 12345" | tr -d '[:alpha:][:blank:][:punct:]'
312345
```

You can also make a pattern that gets the number after the first ":"

Comment: But the IDs are different all the times and I need to save 3 different IDs.

Comment: So you need an awk PROGRAM line that outputs the number in the string. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329185/how-to-print-certain-column-with-numbers-only-in-awk